# How to make an Arduino USB programming circuit?

Tags: usb

I am designing a PCB in which I am using the MCU used in **`Arduino UNO`** which is **`Atmega328P`** and some other components as per my project requirements. I have almost designed the circuit but I am confused with the USB programming part. I want my MCU to be programmed using **`USB B Type`** just like we do it in **`Arduino UNO`**. My friend suggests me to purchase an **`Arduino UNO`** device and program that MCU and then put it in my circuit. But I don't want to do it like this. I have found the [**schematic design**](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-uno-schematic.pdf) but its very confusing. Can anyone help me out with this.?

Comment: Eh. Save yourself the pain and just use ISP.

Comment: Can you explain more.?

Comment: You can use an Arduino to program a bootloader into an ATmega328.  There's even an official [tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoISP) for that.

Comment: I fail to see why you think this is so confusing. If you want the functionality of an Arduino UNO then just duplicate the schematic into your project. Fully. You will end up with two MCUs in your project just like the UNO. BTW these MCUs are quite inexpensive.

Comment: The "core" part of the arduino uno board is the Atmega328P, with the 16MHz oscillator (can be removed if you want to use the internal 8MHz clock - search for optiboot) bypass capacitor(s) (C6, but I suggest you to put another one close to the other pair of power pins), reset circuit (RN1D and, I suggest you, also the button), ICSP connector and, suggested, capacitor C4. You will need an ISP programmer to put at least the bootloader on board. If you want to program through serial, just add a usb-serial converter (suggested: FTDI). If it has also the DTR pin, you can enable auto-reset

Comment: To enable it, just add the capacitor C5 between the reset node and the DTR pin. And that's all. If you want everything on-board, you can use a FT232RL (and its VCP drivers), which does not require you to flash the firmware (like the Atmega16U2 used by the real arduino boards). Otherwise you can use any USB-UART module (and if it has the DTR pin, well, better). I suggest you the FT232RL because I recently got a prolific 2303 cable and.. There are no more drivers for Win8+, while FTDI goes on supporting their products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite a lot simpler to obtain an [FTDI USB - TTL Serial cable](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9718). (The link goes to the American supplier, Sparkfun, but such cables are available from many online suppliers.) They are typically made with a 6-pin female header instead of a USB B connector; you may have to make up that part yourself, if it is important to you. If you only need USB functionality for programming, one cable can serve any number of boards (one at a time, of course), no need to build it into each board.

Comment: Not 100% exact. In fact this requires you to have a Atmega328P with bootloader; commonly sold atmega, however, do not have it, so you will also need the ICSP port to program the bootloader the first time

Comment: It takes only one chip with a bootloader to make an arduino work-alike which can then flash the bootloader into bare chips. A borrowed work-alike can flash that first chip. The OP seems familiar with Arduino and there was no constraint that no Arduino should ever be used

Comment: Totally agree, but... If there is no ICSP connector on the PCB then you will not be able to program it once soldered. Hence, the "not 100% exact", since you can fix it by pre-programming the bootloader, but 1) it's more useful to put an ICSP connector on the PCB (if the bootloader gets corrupted you can flash it again later), and 2) better saying it before the OP solders the IC on the board (and then finds out he can't upload with just a USB-TTL cable)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the schematic design, you need atmega8 to make a usb programming connection. Design your circuit exactly like in the schematic.You will also need bootloader for it, so use any programmer like usbasp, connect its pins to mosi, miso sck, rst,vcc,gnd and click on burn boot loader in arduino ide

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a more permanent option on the board, you could also add a USB to FTDI chip like this: http://www.mouser.com/Search/m_ProductDetail.aspx?FTDI%2fFT232RL-REEL%2f&qs=D1%2fPMqvA103RC6OU6bKtoA%3d%3d&gclid=CNmDjr7dvssCFYZefgod9jgPeQ

Comment: Again, this requires you to already have a Atmega328P with bootloader